# How to make an iframe tag behave like a div, without scrolling and without having to hide the overflowed content

Tags: html, css, iframe

Suppose I have the following html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make the iframe behave like a div, without scrolling and without having to hide the overflowed content.

Answer (score 1):

Add `scrolling="no" style=" width: 100%; height: 1000vh;  overflow: hidden;"` attribute to the iframe.